# PYTHON | stop user killing process

Tags: python, process-management

A very cool function was mentioned here:

[Prevent user process from being killed with "End Process" from Process Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185975/prevent-user-process-from-being-killed-with-end-process-from-process-explorer)

Does anyone know how to translate this C++ code to Python (or re-edit it so that it at least compiles in C/C++, assuming that is what it is in):

```
static const bool ProtectProcess()
{
    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS denyAccess = {0};
    DWORD dwAccessPermissions = GENERIC_WRITE|PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS|WRITE_DAC|DELETE|WRITE_OWNER|READ_CONTROL;
    BuildExplicitAccessWithName( &denyAccess, _T("CURRENT_USER"), dwAccessPermissions, DENY_ACCESS, NO_INHERITANCE );
    PACL pTempDacl = NULL;
    DWORD dwErr = 0;
    dwErr = SetEntriesInAcl( 1, &denyAccess, NULL, &pTempDacl );
    // check dwErr...
    dwErr = SetSecurityInfo( hProcess, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, pTempDacl, NULL );
    // check dwErr...
    LocalFree( pTempDacl );
    CloseHandle( hProcess );
    return dwErr == ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to make it harder for a user to terminate a process?

Comment: What do you mean by edit it so that it compiles as C++. Does it not compile? Looks like a pretty easy port to Pythin via ctypes.

Comment: Would appreciate ctype example wrt above

Comment: So, did you appreciate the ctypes sample?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rather crude ctypes translation of the code you posted. It even appears to work! Note that I remove the call to `CloseHandle` which is simply wrong. You should not call `CloseHandle` on a pseudo-handle, which is what [`GetCurrentProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns.

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import *
from win32con import *

class TRUSTEE(Structure):
    pass

TRUSTEE._fields_ = (
    ('pMultipleTrustee', POINTER(TRUSTEE)),
    ('MultipleTrusteeOperation', c_int),
    ('TrusteeForm', c_int),
    ('TrusteeType', c_int),
    ('ptstrName', LPSTR)
)

class EXPLICIT_ACCESS(Structure):
    _fields_ = (
        ('grfAccessPermissions', DWORD),
        ('grfAccessMode', c_int),
        ('grfInheritance', DWORD),
        ('Trustee', TRUSTEE)
    )

GetCurrentProcess = windll.kernel32.GetCurrentProcess
GetCurrentProcess.restype = HANDLE
hProcess = GetCurrentProcess()

denyAccess = EXPLICIT_ACCESS()
dwAccessPermissions = DWORD(GENERIC_WRITE|PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS|WRITE_DAC|DELETE|WRITE_OWNER|READ_CONTROL);

BuildExplicitAccessWithName = windll.advapi32.BuildExplicitAccessWithNameA
BuildExplicitAccessWithName.restype = None
DENY_ACCESS = 3
NO_INHERITANCE = 0
BuildExplicitAccessWithName(byref(denyAccess), 'CURRENT_USER', dwAccessPermissions, DENY_ACCESS, NO_INHERITANCE)

SetEntriesInAcl = windll.advapi32.SetEntriesInAclA
SetEntriesInAcl.restype = DWORD
SetEntriesInAcl.argtypes = (ULONG, POINTER(EXPLICIT_ACCESS), c_voidp, POINTER(c_voidp))
pTempDacl = c_voidp()
dwErr = SetEntriesInAcl(1, byref(denyAccess), None, byref(pTempDacl));

SetSecurityInfo = windll.advapi32.SetSecurityInfo
SetSecurityInfo.restype = DWORD
SetSecurityInfo.argtypes = (HANDLE, c_int, DWORD, c_voidp, c_voidp, c_voidp, c_voidp)
SE_KERNEL_OBJECT = 6
dwErr = SetSecurityInfo(hProcess, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, None, None, pTempDacl, None);

LocalFree = windll.kernel32.LocalFree
LocalFree.restype = c_voidp
LocalFree.argtypes = (c_voidp,)
LocalFree(pTempDacl)
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me by the way, so I would guess that it is a viable translation.

Comment: Why can I still close the script on Task Manager after this? Does this still work? (Windows 7 x64, Python 3.6.6 x32)

Answer (score 1):

How about using [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html)? You could also try [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). You could also try using [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/). For ActivePython there is [win32api](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32api.html).

Also, I don't know your reasoning behind why you want to achieve that, which means there is potentially some more elegant solution available.

Comment: It gives you some pointers from where you can start looking from for more information. The question you are asking is in itself non-trivial, which means you will need to do some non-trivial coding to completely solve it :) Alternatively, you could provide us with a rationale why you want to achieve what you are doing and we could suggest some alternative solutions.

Comment: I am writing a user productivity module for application usage monitoring - managed by admins - no good if it can be killed by users. I can run as a service, but then all win32gui items fail. This seems like a good / simple alternative.

Comment: Keep the GUI separate and run as a service. That's the *right* solution.

Comment: I can run as a service - but key function calls such as win32gui.GetForegroundWindow fail.

Comment: @Ian You need two processes. One to perform the admin and logging, and one to show GUI.