# Event for track end task application on windows with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, exit, taskmanager

I have a executable program with **python 3.7**, I want to track if user closed app with **taskmanger** then program do something.

Actually I used [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html), but this library not working on end task or process ending.

Is there any way to handle this?

my info:

- python 3.7
- windows 10
- pyinstaller 3.4

Comment: thanks @eryksun, I saw this answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313126/detect-end-process-from-task-manager-in-c-sharp) but how can I use this? can you answer with example ?

Comment: Actually my program runs in background, and its now gui or console. but i think console solution can works for me.

Comment: No, it won't. The console solution requires being attached to a console to get a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` when the console window is closed. For a background program that's not a service, you're going to have to create a thread that owns a hidden window, and the window procedure should handle `WM_CLOSE` by calling `sys.exit`. That should work with taskkill.exe. IIRC, Task Manager requires a visible window.