# How can a powershell script detect when task manager has killed it?

Tags: powershell, windows-11

I have a `powershell` script that normal runs as foreground process (i.e. an app, on my desktop in a `powerhshell` console)

The script is coded such that when `ctrl+c` is pressed it will go through an orderly shutdown and close.

The script is currently being run as a background process (i.e. no console), but I still need to make it go through an orderly shutdown when it closes. I need to be able to do one of two things....

1. Modify the script to detect when task manager has killed it and do an orderly shutdown (same as when `ctrl+c` is used normally), OR
2. Send the equivalent of a `ctrl+c` from task manager.

Comment: You can't intercept and End Process sent from Task Manager, but End Task [will send](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12313209/503046) an event.

Comment: Check if running `taskkill` vs your process without force flag triggers your termination routine. If not, you should implement some means of receiving either Windows messages, or TCP/UDP packets (or pipes, or whatever other channel of message processing there is) to trigger graceful termination.