# how to make a process unstoppable in our programs?

Tags: python, windows, vb6, taskmanager

There are some process in the *Windows-Task-Manager* that you can't kill them in Non-Administrator users :

[image]

And even in Administrator users, when you try to kill them, you receive this below warning :

[image]

I want to know, is there any way to make another program's process like this? i.e if I want to write a program with *VB6* or *Python* for example, is there any way to prevent the user to kill its process? (having this behavior, or a similar behavior that prevent stopping it)

Comment: its trojan, what the hell its doing in ur pc???

Comment: @Hackaholic No, It isn't. It's a monitoring software to monitor the system of clients in my network, And I want to prevent them to stop it.

Comment: @Hackaholic In the other word I want to see if they do what they paid for or not. They will be aware of this software, I just want to prevent killing it.

Comment: Have a look to this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OFntE4bowU

Comment: Revoke PROCESS_TERMINATE permission; possible duplicate of [Prevent user process from being killed with "End Process" from Process Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185975/prevent-user-process-from-being-killed-with-end-process-from-process-explorer)

Comment: @Hackaholic Oops! I misunderstood your comment! No it is not a Trojan! It is one of primary and mandatory system processes! What kind of hacker you really are?! I think you **MUST** memorize the name of these processes if you want to be a hacker.

Comment: Addressing the second part of the question, about the warning from Task Manager: there's no way to do that, other than (maybe!) making the name of your executable csrss.exe, which is probably a bad idea.  Task Manager has a hard-coded list of processes that it warns you about, there's no way to modify the list.